# Need help for Vim Regular Expression

Tags: regex, vim

I try to come up a regular expression to capture the following pattern:

I want to include the characters from **a-z**, but exclude **e**, **f** and **g** 
I know the characters class in Vim

```
[^efg]
```

**excludes characters**: **e, f** and **g**

I have tried follwoing regular expression

```
%s/[a-z[^efg]]//gc
```

but it doesn't capture what I want

Comment: Try `\([efg]\)\@![a-z]`

Answer (score 5):

You could consider using the other ranges that you need (i.e. `[a-d]` and `[h-z]`) within a single character group, which should match every character except those you explicitly excluded:

```
[a-dh-z]
```

**Example**

[image]

You can [see an interactive example of this here](https://regex101.com/r/hZ7tD2/1).

Comment: Above just an example to illustrate my problem, my real problem is more complicated that just a few characters. I'm looking for more general solution.

Comment: Can you provide a more detailed example of what some of your real-world input / output might look like?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do that:

```
:%s/[efg]\@!.//g
```

Because `\@!` do negative/inverse match.